# Create new button not working - eZ Publish

Tags: ezpublish

I have multiple language on site , so in Admin panel  not work button "Create new" in ger-DE but working in  eng-GB
i have no idea  what is reason of this issue.

It is my siteAccess for ger-DE

```
[RegionalSettings]
Locale=ger-DE
ContentObjectLocale=ger-DE
SiteLanguageList[]
SiteLanguageList[]=eng-GB
SiteLanguageList[]=ger-DE
```

if i will change like this

```
    [RegionalSettings]
    Locale=ger-DE
    ContentObjectLocale=ger-DE
    SiteLanguageList[]
    SiteLanguageList[]=ger-DE
    SiteLanguageList[]=eng-GB
```

Than it working. but half of admin panel is on english . what i`m do wrong ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translate all classes  to all  languages and it`s  work now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `TextTranslation` option to `enabled`, too which enables translating the interface. Complete example:

```
[RegionalSettings]
Locale=ger-DE
ContentObjectLocale=ger-DE
SiteLanguageList[]
SiteLanguageList[]=ger-DE
SiteLanguageList[]=eng-GB
TextTranslation=enabled
```

Note that you also need to clear ALL the caches for this change to work.

Comment: First of all thank`s for reply , strange but it still not working :( i try all possibility variants but without success

Comment: Translation is working , everything is on German  but  this button "Create new " is not clickable

Comment: You can then mark the answer as solved :) 

Button not working might be a separate issue. Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: But  my issue was  this button  not translation  :) maybe i ask question wrong  sorry  but main issue was this button,  about console errors it`s clear , no one error is appear.

Comment: On english languadge it`s working   but not working on German only!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said that if you set your configuration to your second example, then it works, but the interface is English. Setting `TextTranslation` to `enabled` will switch the interface to German and keep the button working, right?

Comment: Yes you are right!  everything is working and translating   but  not working only this button, other buttons all works perfectly. It`s only on German , i have 2 lang, German and English

Comment: Check if your users have permissions to create new content in German language and check if German language is added to the list in `/content/translations` page. Other than that, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work :/

Comment: Nope, I`m signed with  Administrator  user who have no limit   role :/

Comment: Are you using eZ Publish 5? If yes, did you also setup new stack side of the siteaccess config in `ezpublish/config/ezpublish.yml` ? Configuration there should match the configuration in legacy INI files.

Comment: Yes , i use eZ Publish 5,
About siteaccess,   Yes i have setup  them . everything i made as it is  in eZ DOC.

Comment: Did you also add German language to your admin siteaccess in `ezpublish.yml`?

Comment: I check it with another database and it`s work , so it is not  code fault, it`s something  from database , maybe some Role  or access to creat new content ,  But i wonder if Is Admin  have  all access or not.

Comment: As I already mentioned, the only thing that makes sense is that German language is not added to the list of available languages in `/content/translations`. Can't think of any more reasons :(

Comment: I assume i already did this. Please see my dashboard screen
https://ibb.co/gDemoa

Comment: Than, unfortunatelly, I am at loss as much as you are.

Comment: Ok, Thank you anyway!